# Как из строки QlineEdit получить long Double,

Tags: c++, qt

В общем строку знаю как превратить в Double, а как в строку в long Double незню ;_;

```
dump_ID.n_s_T[0] = 0;
if (ui->lE_t1->text()->isEmpty())
    dump_ID.n_s_T[0] = numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
else
    dump_ID.n_s_T[0] = ui->lE_t1->text().toLDouble();
```

В общем еще расматриваю как массив превратить в long double :3

Answer (score 3):

Ну нет в Qt API отдельной поддержки long double. Смирись. Набросай пару обёрток для конвертации QString STL'евскими или C'шными функциями:

```
long double qstrtold (const QString & str) {
    // TODO: добавить обработку ошибок по вкусу.
    return rv = strtold (str.toLatin1().data(), NULL);
}
```

Comment: Это боль ...                     моя  жизнь сплошная мука  _;

Comment: сочувствую, бро...